# Failed to bind the combobox in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

In the below sample, I try to bind the `PartNumber` to load into `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, but I couldn't able to do it. How can I do this?

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    public List<Parts> PartsList { get; set; }
}

public class Parts
{
    public string PartName { get; set; }
    public double PartQuantity { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgrStavke"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          Height="160"
          Width="600"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="5"
          Grid.Row="7"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="ValueCombo"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PartsList}"
                            DisplayMemberPath="PartNumber">
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I don't think that binding is correct. Check visual studio output window for binding errors.

Comment: If you've set your `DataContext` properly, using just `ItemsSource="{Binding PartsList}"` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **ObservableCollection** instead of **List** .If you want to use list then you will have to notify it. But the best way is to use ObservableCollection. I hope this will help.

I just have seen that ItemSource of ComboBox is also not correct it should be like

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Order.PartsList}"
```

Comment: He will . If He will use Add,Remove,Insert,Delete methods of List to add,remove items then nothing will be notified or he will have to notify it explicitly after these methods. It will be notified only if he will assign the value to list using = operator